# how to assign class1.prototype = Object.create(class2.prototype)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am currently learning ES6 and I know that classes is just sugar topping and they still follow prototype inheritance of javascript.

In the methods we can assign

```
Method1.prototype = Object.create(Method2.prototype)
```

and class uses extends key work to create inheritance.

Is there any way apart from `extends` to do

```
Class1.prototype = Object.create(class1.prototype)
```

I tried doing `class1.prototype` but it is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I want to know is there any way to access class methods of different class which are not related to each other

Comment: Yes, but not with `Object.create`, which would relate them to each other - it's just inheritance. Please post your whole code so that we can try to figure out what you are doing and what does not work.

Answer (score 0):

To extend a class, set the `prototype` value to:

```
ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
```

This way, you can still assign to the prototype of the `ChildClass`.
If you directly assign `ChildClass.prototype = ParentClass.prototype`, you cannot define `ChildClass` methods and properties.

Comment: already tried not working, it only working if I am using methods

Comment: @ANMo It should work, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#With_Object.create